# WordPress filter table

Tags: wordpress, filter

How could I modify [this extension](http://tablepress.org/extensions/row-filter/)  to be [like this](http://www.sportksa.net/main/saudi-arabian-championships/prof).

I want to make drop down filter instead of the search filter box.

Or can anyone tell me if there is another extension that offers what I need in the second table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tabulizer for Wordpress. It supports "select from list" column filters, as described in this tutorial: http://www.tabulizer.com/index.php/support-menu/tabulizer-tips/81-wordpress-advanced-table-search-capabilities